# Why Is Castle Windsor MVC Not Working On Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I have added Castle Windsor MVC package to my project to facilitate DI. Is works fine on my local machine. But when I deploy to the server I get this on the page:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Description: An
> unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
> request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
> error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
> constructor defined for this object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
> object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
> Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
> RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
> skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +190
> System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +114
> System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
> requestContext, Type controllerType) +75
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
> controller of type
> 'MyApp.Controllers.MyController'. Make sure that
> the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
> requestContext, Type controllerType) +242
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
> requestContext, String controllerName) +96
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
> +255    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +112
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +840    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +224    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +131

It's as if the Windsor files are not loading?

As this is happening on the server I have no way to debug. All files and configs are the same. Can someone advise as to what the cause may be or how to troubleshoot this?

I am using .Net 4.5.2 if that matters. Server is Windows 2012 R2 with IIS 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably need to verify that 1) the same .NET Framework versions are installed on the server, 2) that the AppPool is running in Integrated Mode and set to use .NET Framework 4.0, and 3) that RAMFAR (RunAllModulesForAllRequests) is enabled in the system.webServer section of the web.config

Comment: Did you mean runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests? I couldn't find RunAllModulesForAllRequests.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I was typing that from memory.